# Problema al calcular ecuación

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código, el cual debe calcular la altura y velocidad de un objeto en caída libre en tiempo real (actualizando los valores cada segundo). Sin embargo, no lo calcula bien:

```
from os import system
from time import sleep

# La altura es expresada en metros
# La velocidad es expresada en metros por segundo
# El tiempo transcurrido es expresado en segundos
# La gravedad es expresada en metros por segundo al cuadrado

altura = 1960
altura_inicial = altura
gravedad = 9.8
velocidad = 0
tiempo = 0

while True:
    system("cls")
    print("El objeto caerá desde " + str(altura_inicial) + " metros de altura con " + str(gravedad) + " de gravedad.\n")
    print("Luego de " + str(tiempo) + " segundos, el objeto está a " + str(altura) + " metros de altura.")

    input("Presione ENTER para aumentar el tiempo en un segundo...")

    altura = altura - (0.5 * gravedad * (tiempo ** 2))
    tiempo += 1
```

Comment: ... "no lo calculaba bien". Si nos cuentas cual resultado obtienes y cual resultado esperas, podriamos empezar a trabajar en el tema. Si no, será puro adivinar. Edita tu pregunta y completa la información.

Comment: Ejecutalo, si pongo que la gravedad es 9.8 y la altura es 1960, debe tardar 20 segundos exactos en lograr que la altura sea 0

Comment: Además, descubrí que si disminuyo el valor de el sleep y el valor por el que se aumenta el tiempo, el objeto disminuirá la altura mas lento, porque?

Comment: Voy a editar la pregunta con un código que hace más facil ver las operaciones en el tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: @CandidMoe Descubrí que es python calculando mal la ecuación, 1960 - (0.5 * gravedad * (tiempo ** 2)) me debería dar 0, pero da -2. Además 4.9*400 debería dar 1960, pero da 1960.0000000000002

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo con la física, para un objeto en caida líbre, la distancia recorrida y velocidad estan dadas por

```
altura = 1/2 * g * t ^ 2
velocidad = g * t
```

Reescribe el código para mostrar los datos segundo a segundo de la caida.

```
altura = 1960
gravedad = 9.8
velocidad = 0
tiempo = 0
caida = 0

print("Tiempo\tAltura\tVelocidad\tCaida")
while altura > caida:
    print(f"{tiempo}\t\t{altura - caida:.1f}\t{velocidad:.1f}\t\t{caida:.1f}")
    tiempo += 1
    velocidad = gravedad * tiempo
    caida = tiempo ** 2 * gravedad / 2
```

produce

```
Tiempo  Altura  Velocidad   Caida
0       1960.0  0.0     0.0
1       1955.1  9.8     4.9
2       1940.4  19.6        19.6
3       1915.9  29.4        44.1
4       1881.6  39.2        78.4
5       1837.5  49.0        122.5
6       1783.6  58.8        176.4
7       1719.9  68.6        240.1
8       1646.4  78.4        313.6
9       1563.1  88.2        396.9
10      1470.0  98.0        490.0
11      1367.1  107.8       592.9
12      1254.4  117.6       705.6
13      1131.9  127.4       828.1
14      999.6   137.2       960.4
15      857.5   147.0       1102.5
16      705.6   156.8       1254.4
17      543.9   166.6       1416.1
18      372.4   176.4       1587.6
19      191.1   186.2       1768.9
```

La variable `caida` es la distancia recorrida durante el segundo en cuestión.

Answer (score 1):

Compartiré mi solución a pesar que Moe ya hizo una.
Además, para el calculo, este cambio soluciona el problema que el tiene.

Debo agregar que el problema inicial era debido a un mal calculo de la altura. Y que la mejor solución es conocer la altura incial, y cuanto ha caído el objeto. Luego restar esos valores.

```
from os import system
from time import sleep

altura_i = 1960
altura = 1960
gravedad = 9.8
velocidad = 0
tiempo = 0
caida = 0

while tiempo <= 20:
    print("Caida: " + str(round(caida)))
    print("Altura: " + str(altura))
    print("Tiempo: " + str(tiempo))
    print("");
    tiempo += 1
    caida = (0.5 * gravedad * (tiempo ** 2))
    altura = altura_i - round(caida)
```